please suggest a good free video compressor website or software
my os- win11,cpu ryzen5 7600,Ram - 32gb ddr5, gpu - AMD rx 7800xt ,
can someone please suggest a good  free video compressor website or software which can reduce the video file size much but without losing much quality. also it should support atleast 3gb file size as input (unlimited file size support would be awesome and much needed too).

thank you very much.
